# VBA code to identify blanks in a column. If a blank is found delete the whole row. If no blanks are found move to the next step

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that searches for blanks and deletes the whole row. But I'm getting an error when it doesn't find a blank. How do I change my code to say if a blank if found, delete the whole row. If no blanks are found, move on. Not sure how to loop it or wrap it in IfError.

```
Dim Lastrow As Long
Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range("K3:K" & Lastrow).Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

I tried this, but got a memory error.

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("K3:K" & Lastrow)
Rows = rng.Rows.Count
For i = Rows To 1 Step (-1)
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng.Rows(i)) = 0 Then rng.Rows(i).Delete
 Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check with an IF if there is any blank cell before executing that part o code:

```
Sub test()
Dim Lastrow As Long

Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

'check for blank cells
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Range("K3:K" & Lastrow)) > 0 Then
    Range("K3:K" & Lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Delete Shift:=xlUp
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked to remove the row when it found blank and when no blanks were found, I didn't get an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the error if no blanks are found:

```
Dim blanks As Range

With ActiveSheet  'or some specific worksheet...
    On Error Resume Next 'ignore error if no blanks
    Set blanks = .Range("K3:K" & .Cells(.Rows.Count,"A").End(xlUp).Row). _
                 SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error Goto 0     'stop ignoring errors
End With

'delete if any blanks found
If Not blanks Is Nothing then blanks.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer Tim. I still received a debug message saying No Cells Found on the Set blanks step.

Comment: Then likely you have your VBA options for error handling set to "Break on All Errors"  Try changing that to "Break in Class Module" instead.  In the VB editor under *Tools >> Options >> General >> Error Trapping*

Comment: I didn't even know that existed. I've never used a class module. Mine is on "Break on Unhandled Errors". I tried your code outside of my larger macro, without changing the error handling and it worked except it only deleted the cell and not the row. I'm also curious what the "A" means in your code.

Comment: If you want to remove the whole row then you can use `blanks.EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp`   From above `.Cells(.Rows.Count,"A")` is the last cell in Column A.  Same as `.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1)` since that second argument can be either a valid column header or a numeric value.